# Can't get all data from table with laravel raw query and group_concat

Tags: sql, laravel-4

Although I have 3 different teacher reports on the table and all the dates are same,  i can only get last teacher's report

```
        $report = DB::table('users')
        ->join('classreports', 'classreports.teacherId', '=', 'users.id')
        ->where('classreports.classId', '=', Input::get('classId'))
        ->where('classreports.reportDate', '=', $reportDate)
        ->groupBy('classreports.reportDate')
        ->select('users.fullName', 'classreports.reportDate', DB::raw('group_concat(classreports.report) as report'))
        ->get();
    return json_encode($report);
```

How can i get all teacher's report?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
        ->groupBy('classreports.teacherId','classreports.reportDate')
```

Can group by `teacherID` and `reportDate`

Comment: if i want to add new join like this: ->join('subject', 'users.id', '=', 'subject.teacherId') and then add to groupBy  'subject.teacherId' field it returns last teacher's report again.

Comment: can you please tell me,  other 2 teacher record is exist in subject table ?

Comment: thanks for help, i have solved, as you said there was no records for subjectTitle. Now it works properly.